# How to write "install" target in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am new to `Makefile` and like to write an `install` target in `Makefile`. My `Makefile` is going to be called from another `Makefile` like this:

```
DESTDIR=$(DIR_A) BINDIR=/dir_b make -C $(CURDIR)/xxxx/yyy all
```

where `/xxxx/yyy` is where my `Makefile` is located.

My `Makefile` is going to generate 2 binaries that I like to install them i.e. by install, I mean to copy both of the binaries to a specific directory (`BINDIR`) and make them executable.

How should I write the `install` target in this case if my 2 binaries are generated in `/aaaa/bbbb/bin` folder?

Comment: Look at "man install" as a start

Comment: A makefile has no "tags", but rules. Reading a tutorial should help (there comes one with GNU make).

Comment: @Olaf It has "targets". The rules are for building the targets.

Answer (score 2):

"Install" is going to be a "phony" target. And I strongly advise to use utility `install` instead of `cp` and `chmod`:

```
.PHONY: install
install:
    install -m 557 /aaaa/bbbb/bin/first /aaaa/bbbb/bin/second $BINDIR
```

Now, you can do `make install`.

Comment: I was testing it and I added a dummy folder as the destination.

I did

```
install: mkdir temp_dir
           install -m 755 /aaaa/bbbb/bin/first temp_dir
```
However, I only see "install' is up to date", and I do not see the temp_dir folder created. Do you know why?

Comment: In fact, something strange is going on. I gave a wrong path to my binaries (such as /cccc/dddd/bin/first), which does not exist. make install still returns "install is up to date". Why does it not return an error?

Comment: When dealing with make files, it is very important to see their actual layout. Could you perhaps make your make file a part of the question? I did try my make file, and I added `mkdir` to it, and everything works.

Comment: Please add the `install` target into `.PHONY`! Test: `touch install && make install` - maybe you'll surprise! :) And I think `install`'s requirements should be `/aaa/bbb/bin/first` and `.../second` (what do you want copy if they aren't exists?). Please expand your answer because it's uncomplate.

Comment: @uzsolt Agree with .PHONY. Disagree with install (`man install`).